# Basic Regular Expression URL Matching

Tags: regex, google-analytics

Im in the process of learning regular expressions but still cant really wrap my head around it quite yet. However I need to create one for Google Analytics and was hoping someone could help out.

Currently my Goal page is head-match:

> /checkout/cart?complete

and funnel step:

> /checkout/onepage

The problem is that the funnel step could be several different slightly different URLs. It could be:

> /checkout/onepage
>
> /checkout/onepage/index
>
> /checkout/multishipping/login
>
> /checkout/multishipping/billing
>
> /checkout/multishipping/shipping

Can anyone tell me what the expression would be to "lump" those 5 potential URLs as the same thing? Also, what would I change my Goal url to if the potential outcomes could be one of the below examples:

> /checkout/cart?complete=10000245 <-- (single order)
>
> /checkout/cart?complete=10000245,10000246,10000247 <-- (multiship order)

I know I would have to escape the question mark first but after that Im not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your goal page you'll want to use the `+ ?` and `*` operators.

```
/checkout/cart\?complete(=(\d+,?)*)?
```

For funnel you'll want the `|` and `?` operators

```
/checkout/(onepage(/index)?|multishipping/(login|billing|shipping))
```